# Removing first character from string

Tags: python

I am working on a CodeEval challenge and have a solution to a problem which takes a list of numbers as an input and then outputs the sum of the digits of each line. Here is my code to make certain you understand what I mean:

```
import sys
test_cases = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
for test in test_cases:
    if test:
        num = int(test)
        total =0
        while num != 0:
            total += num % 10
            num /= 10
        print total


test_cases.close()
```

I am attempting to rewrite this where it takes the number as a string, slices each 0-index, and then adds those together (curious to see what the time and memory differences are - totally new to coding and trying to find multiple ways to do things as well)

However, I am stuck on getting this to execute and have the following:

```
import sys
test_cases = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
for test in test_cases:
    sums = 0
    while test:
      sums = sums + int(str(test)[0])
      test = test[1:]
    print sums

test_cases.close()
```

I am receiving a "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''"

The sample input is a text file which looks like this:

```
3011
6890
8778
1844
42
8849
3847
8985
5048
7350
8121
5421
7026
4246
4439
6993
4761
3658
6049
1177
```

Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: Instead of getting one char and creating new string without the first char, you can iterate over string to process it char after char. It's more efficent. I mean: `for char in test: sum += int(char)` instead of `while test:...`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that one out too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is the newlines (eg. /n or /r/n) at the end of each line.

Change this line:

```
for test in test_cases:
```

into this to split out the newlines:

```
for test in test_cases.read().splitlines():
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
tot = 0
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        try:
            tot += int(line)
        except ValueError:
            print "Not a number"

print tot
```

- using the context manager (`with...`) the file is automatically closed.
- casting to `int` filter any empty or not valid value

you can substitute `print` with any other statement optimal for you (`raise` or `pass` depending on your goals)